# How to change button text color using Hexa-decimal color value?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-button, textcolor

How to change button text color On Clicking the button using hexa-decimal value? I'm using the below code on **MainActivity** but not working

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           // button.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            button.setTextColor(Color.(#808080));
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Color.parseColor` to get the `int` value of hex color string like below:

```
button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

```
button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the color in your res/values/colors.xml file and use it like this:

`button.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.your_color_name));`

Answer (score 0):

It can be in a two way

**Define Your color in the res/values/colors.xml**

1. Use it on your Activity.java

   button.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.defined_color_name));
2. Use it on activity_name.xml

   ```
           <Button    
           android:id="@+id/button"    
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"    
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
           android:text="My Button"    
           android:textColor="@color/nameOfYourColor"  />
   ```